# Need prove that the $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^3}{3x^2+ 2y^3}$ exists using epsilon-delta.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Prove that the limit is zero:
>   $$ F(x, y)= \frac{x^2y^3}{3x^2+ 2y^3}$$

Definition1. Let $ U ⊂ R^n$  be an open set and letf : $U→R^m$ beafunction with domain U. Let x0 be a vector in U or on the boundary of U. Let b∈Rm. We say that the limit of f as x approaches x0 is b, written
lim f(x) = b, x→x0
provided that for every ε > 0 there is a δ > 0 so that ||f(x)−b|| < ε whenever 0 < ||x − x0|| < δ and x ∈ U.

First:

$ 0\le\sqrt {x^2+y^2} <\delta $ and $ |F(x,y) -0| < \epsilon$

$|\frac{x^2y^3}{3x^2+ 2y^3}| = \frac{x^2|y^3|}{|3x^2+ 2y^3|} = ...$ how can i solve this? Please, help me.

Comment: the limit does not exist. $3 x^2 + 2 y^3 = 0$ is a curve with a cusp at the origin. Your function is not even defined on that curve, and is arbitrarily large near it.

Comment: @WillJagy, for some reason I didn't see your comment until I posted my answer.

Comment: @Barry, right, sometimes comments take a long time to appear. I've got to wonder whether the intended question has $3 x^2 + 2 y^2$ in the denominator, and this OP is one of the many who cannot be bothered to proofread the question after submission. Just checked profile, new user...

Comment: @WillJagy, it's possible the OP *misread* the exponent for the $y$ in the denominator in the original problem (possibly by "continuity" with the $y^3$ in the numerator), but they've used it consistently here, so I don't see how proofreading their submission would've helped.  It's also possible the error resides in the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

The limit actually does not exist.  Here's one way to see why:

Let $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along the curve defined by $2y^3=kx^4-3x^2$.  Then

$${x^2y^3\over3x^2+2y^3}={kx^6-3x^4\over2kx^4}={1\over2}x^2-{3\over2k}\to-{3\over2k}$$

Since we can use any value we like for $k$ (except $0$, of course), we can get any value we like in the limit.

The key here is that you can take cube roots of negative numbers, so that $y=\sqrt[3]{(kx^4-3x^2)/2}$ is defined for all $x$.

Comment: @MyGlasses, thanks, I've fixed it!

Comment: Similar to mine.  (+1)

Comment: @Dr.MV, yes, I saw yours when I posted mine.  I think you beat me by about a minute.

Comment: Barry, you might consider editing in  an answer with denominator $3 x^2 + 2 y^2,$ which becomes a sensible question; that is, the OP may have a typo. Hmmm on the other hand, don't really need total degree five in the numerator then, three would do it. Well, no knowing.

Comment: @BarryCipra Well, they are slightly different.  Whereas your parameter $k$, which appears as a coefficient on $x^4$ shows that the limit fails to exist, my parameter $a$, which appears as an exponent $t^a$, does likewise.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

The limit, $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left(\frac{x^2y^3}{3x^2+2y^3} \right)$,fails to exist.

Examine the limit along the curve described parametrically by $x=t$ and $2y^3=-3t^2+t^a$, $a\ge4$.  Then, note that

$$\left|\frac{x^2y^3}{3x^2+2y^3} \right|=\left|\frac{t^{a-2}+3}{2t^{a-4}} \right|$$

What can one conclude as $t\to 0$?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to given you the best answer I can.  -Mark